# Find simplest function thats the closest estimated possible

Tags: asymptotics, exponential-function

Trying to understand the wording. I imagine Im being asked to find the simplest Big O estimate for this function and my professor just worded it oddly?

$$
2^{\log_2 n}
$$

From my understanding, itd of the family of exponential (2^n).

But how do I go about solving it properly. Unsure if its the right answer though. Id have to find k and c if Im not wrong.

Comment: Your professor is asking you to simplify the expression to see what the $\mathcal{O}$ of it is. Have you tried using exponential rules to simplify it?

Comment: I simplified it and found n^2. so that means, the simplest closest function thats big O of the given function would be n^2?

Comment: Your simplification is incorrect as its not $n^2$, but yes you would say $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ if that was the answer

Comment: @wjmccann Thanks a lot for the confirmation. I found n so O(n).